# MYSQL INSERT with multiple SELECT based on common column

Tags: mysql

I need to insert info from stats table `hits` into `info` table with calculated info from `hits` table

I have this query to insert which is working fine and inserts unique counts based on ip

```
INSERT INTO `stats`.`info`
(`id`,`rate`,`date`,`count_date`,`count_country`,`country`)
(
    SELECT `id`, SUM(s.`rate`) AS `rate`, s.`date` AS `date`, COUNT(s.`ip`) AS `count_date`
    FROM(
        SELECT  
        `id`,`ip`,`rate`,`timestamp`,`date`
        FROM `stats`.`hits
        GROUP BY `date`,`ip`
    ) s
    WHERE (`timestamp` >= '$today' AND `timestamp` < '$nextday') 
    GROUP BY `id`

)
```

Column `count_country` and `country` needs to be inserted from another query for same `id`

The query to get `count_country` and `country`is this

```
SELECT COUNT(s.`ip`) AS `count_country`, `country`
FROM(
    SELECT  
    `ip`,`country`
    FROM `stats`.`hits
    GROUP BY `country`,`ip`
) s
GROUP BY `country`
```

Is it possibe to add this query to INSERT query so that it inserts data for same `id`

Thanks

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry I will try and update